# TCPServer started inside flask : KeyboardInterrupt not caught when tcp handler has a while loop

Tags: python, multithreading, flask, tcpserver

I have a flask controller which starts a tcpserver on demand. I am posting a simplified version of the code.

```
@app.route("/")
def hello():
    scenario_server = MyTCPServer(('localhost', 9000), MyTCPHandler)
    server_thread = threading.Thread(target=scenario_server.serve_forever)
    server_thread.daemon = True
    server_thread.start()
    return "TCP server started"
```

The `MyTCPServer` is a normal `SocketServer.TCPServer`. This is an example of a simple `MyTCPHandler`.

```
class MyTCPHandler(SocketServer.BaseRequestHandler):
    def handle(self):
        while True:
            data = self.request.recv(1024).strip().decode('ascii')
            if data == "HELLO":
                self.request.sendall('COUCOU'.encode('ascii'))
            else:
                break
```

And I start my app application in the `__main__` the standard way (using the built in server `app.run(threaded=True)`)

After I launch the tcpserver, I connect to it using `telnet` and send `HELLO`

With this code and the previous scenario, if I press CTRL+C, the main thread will caught it but it won't kill the program. It seems that the thread running the TCPServer is not killed even if the thread is run with `daemon = True`

However If I modify my handler to change this :

```
data = self.request.recv(1024).strip().decode('ascii')
if data == "":
    break
```

On CTRL+C, it properly exits the program.

Anybody could explain why ?